Nextjs Image not rendering
I am trying to put an image in my hero section but all I can see is the alt tag, I dontknow whats wrong with the image because when I change the src to be the favicon, the image starts to show
[eCode for the situatio](https://i.sstatic.net/2fpntNnM.png)
I tried changing the src, changing the image extensions but none worked

Is your image is absolute in public folder of next js ?

Apart from the link syntax being broken, please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors and prefer to use the StackOverflow recommended service for images, imgur. Also please take the [tour] and read [ask]. You might profit from https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

@ALFaizAhmed Please keep in mind that the staging ground is for helping to make a good question, but not for answering. You might notice that there is no "Post Your Answer" button here. So please don't. You are not helping the question author that way, because you restrict the normally huge number of knowledgable and helpfully minded people to just you and others who use the staging ground other than intended. You can point out missing information that should be added, so if that is what you meant sorry, but please be more explicit; e.g. "You should add information on ... to the question."

@Yunnosch yeah I am asking the author of the question about more information related to his problem in the first statement

@user23543747 Please add folder structure of your project & image tag code. Please Insert code as text, don't put code as image, it gets difficult to type your code. Use images to explain issues which are difficult to explain in words.
